# How to stop annoying informative gray area to appear in Altium?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

It is might come across off topic. But, it is somehow related to PCB design. So, I'd like to ask how prevent this information giving gray area to appear and disappear every time I move the mouse on something. It distracts me and covers the areas that I want to investigate more carefully.
[image]

Comment: I have no idea of that thing, but it seems like it already tells you, did you try "Toggle Heads Up" key combos?

Comment: @PlasmaHH , thanks, it is a great tool indeed! But, I still unable to get rid of that information giving box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As shown in the heads-up display (HUD), Shift-H toggles it on/off. If you press the key combination Shift-H it will hide it. You can also access this control by going to the "View" menu, go down to "Board Insight", and uncheck "Toggle Heads-Up Display". Note that you must be focused in the PCB editor for this shortcut or menu navigation to work.